# Retrieve custom SQL entries in Django login

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-views

Here is my `models.py` file of my `auth` app: [which creates a `auth_article` table in `sql`]

```
from django.db import models
class Article(models.Model):
    title=models.TextField()
    content=models.TextField()
```

However, I'm unable to retrieve `auth_article` fields from `sql` on login.
I'm using the `User` models for login.

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from auth.models import Article

def login_user(request):
    state = "Please login below..."
    username = password = ''
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                state = "You're successfully logged in!"
                user_info = dict(username=username, email=user.email, fullname=user.get_full_name(), id=user.id)
                aa=Article.objects.all()
                return render_to_response('home.html', aa)
...
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the render_to_response docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response

It should be like:

```
return render_to_response('home.html', {'articles': aa}, RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I can't understand from the docs. I tried doing some stuff, but only messing it up. Could be please tell me how can I pass `sql` entries of `auth_article` to my `home.html`?

Comment: Like in my code as dictionary `{'articles': aa}`. Then you can use it in template `{% for article in articles %} ...`

Comment: Thanks a ton. I wasted almost 2 days on it.
But I had one more doubt. I was trying to get `Article` objects with `creator` equal to `id` [from `user_info`] above. 
But, 
`aa=Article.objects.get(creator=id)` didn't work.

Comment: Should be `aa=Article.objects.filter(creator=user)`

Comment: I managed to achieve it by doing: `aa=Article.objects.filter(creator=user.id)`.
Still, can you explain it to me why can't i do `creator=id` when `id=user.id` was defined above?

Comment: Also, I know I'm asking too much, could you answer this question? I'm a newbie in django/Python and struggling on my own out here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029730/load-css-images-in-django